# Is it possible to rewrite $\log(\log(x))?$

Tags: logarithms, regression

I'm doing some exploratory data analysis of `x` and `y` variables on a scatterplot.
[image]

I log transformed the x axis and had a better linear fit:
[image]

From just playing around I tried `log(log(x))`:
[image]

My end goal is to build a linear regression model. From here it looks like `y` is related to `x` via `log(log(x))` transformation.

My question is, does this 'type' of relationship have a name, other than just log log x?

Is it possible to rewrite it using the properties of logs in some other form? I gave it a try and could not, it seems it's just log(log(x)) is the only way to write it. Is that right?

Comment: "Log-log" is fine.

Comment: No, we usually write it as $\log\log x,$ but it doesn’t have another form.

Comment: Alright, thank you for verifying that I was unsure!

Comment: I'm not convinced graphically that this is a log-log linear relationship. Is there any other evidence you have for this?

Comment: You can rewrite with the change of base formula.

Comment: @DonThousand I don't have any other evidence, just the level of exploration in the charts that you see. But I'm open to suggestions if you have any?! Does this indicate another potential relationship?

Comment: @TymaGaidash could you expand on that? Why would we do that here?

Comment: @DougFir  For example: $$\ln(\ln(x))=\frac{\log_b(\ln(x))}{\log_b(e)}= \frac{\log_b(\log_b(x))-\log_b(\log_b(e))}{\log_b(e)} $$ since:$$\frac{\log_b(a)}{\log_b(e)}=\ln(x)$$ Does this help?

Comment: @DougFir The data "fans out" even more after your log-log transform of $x$. So while it solves the apparent non-linearity in the plot, the "equal error variance assumption" that is typically used in linear regression is now inappropriate.

Comment: @0XLR I thought about that too but have no solutions to work around it... do you know of any approaches here?

Comment: Thanks for the info @TymaGaidash it's good to know. When I posted I guess I was wondering if there was a way of simplifying or if I'd touched on a pattern by some other name but I guess from the comments further up it's just 'log log x'

Comment: @DougFir Where did you get the data?

Comment: @0XLR it's cumulative revenue growth for an app. E.g. Suppose over a year we have 365 'cohorts'. For each cohort we track cumulative revenue growth on days 1:365. If revenue is 100 on 1/1/2020 and then this cohort spends another 50 on 1/2/2020 then cumulative revenue is 150 and cumulative revenue growth for this observation is ```log(150) - log(100)``` = 0.4054651. This is the context.